# How can I draw a Bayesian network for this problem with birds?

Tags: bayesian-networks, bayesian-optimization, bayesian-probability

I am working on the following problem to gain an understanding of Bayesian networks and I need help drawing it:

> Birds frequently appear in the tree outside of your window in the morning and evening; these include finches, cardinals and robins. Finches appear more frequently than robins, and robins appear more frequently than cardinals (the ratio is 7:4:1). The finches will sing a song when they appear 7 out of every 10 times in the morning, but never in the evening. The cardinals rarely sing songs and only in the evenings (in the evening, they sing 1 of every 10 times they appear). Robins sing once every five times they appear regardless of the time of day. Every tenth cardinal and robin will stay in the tree longer than five minutes. Every fourth finch will stay in the tree longer than five minutes.

I have tried drawing two versions of the network and would love some feedback. Currently, I am leaning more towards the right side network.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Where did you get that problem from?

Comment: i like the second version of the artificial neural network.